# I can't run a android project on my Zenphone 5

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build, android-build

I have a problem with the marked area in the image below.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I have fixed the problem through you guys suggestion. Thanks!! :)

Comment: Can you mark one of the answer that helped you ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see a popup dialog on your phone, where you should approve installing app. If there is not a dialog, go to `Developer options`, turn off `USB debugging` and then turn it on. The dialog should come.

Also, as John Joe has mentioned, ASUS devices need `Enable ADB integration` to be turned on (they somehow switch it off, happened on my Zenfone 2).

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the instant run in `File >>Settings >>Build,Execution,Deployment >> Instant Run`

and change the USB cable, having Enabled ADB Integration via `Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration`.